# ContentValues not inserting values to the newly added column: Returns null when accessed

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm accessing the following table to retrieve data. But when i do, the last column access gives me a nullpointer exception. This column is a new addition. It worked fine. And the table creation is successfully done. There are no errors.

**This is my table creation query :**

```
String CREATE_ASSIGNMENT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_ASSIGNMENT + "("
            + KEY_ID + " integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+KEY_JOB_NUMBER+" text,"+KEY_TIME_ASSIGNED+" text,"+KEY_TIME_RECEIVED+" text,"
            +KEY_STATUS_READ+" integer DEFAULT 0,"+KEY_STATUS_COMPLETE+" integer DEFAULT 0,"+KEY_ACCIDENT_ADDRESS+" text DEFAULT 'Not Specified',"
            +KEY_ACCIDENT_LAT+" double,"+KEY_ACCIDENT_LNG+" double,"+KEY_VEHICLE_NUMBER+" text DEFAULT 'Not Specified',"+KEY_ENGINE_NUMBER+" text DEFAULT 'Not Specified',"
            +KEY_CHASSIS_NUMBER+" text DEFAULT 'Not Specified',"+KEY_VEHICLE_MAKE_MODEL+" text DEFAULT 'Not Specified',"+KEY_DRIVER_NAME+" text DEFAULT 'Not Specified',"+KEY_DRIVER_CONTACT_NUMBER+" integer DEFAULT 0,"
            +KEY_POLICY_NUMBER+" text DEFAULT 'Not Specified',"+KEY_POLICY_STATUS+" text DEFAULT 'Not Specified',"+KEY_POLICY_PERIOD+" text DEFAULT 'Not Specified',"+KEY_SUM_INSURED+" text DEFAULT 'Not Specified',"
            +KEY_LAST_ENDORSMENT+" text DEFAULT 'Not Specified',"+KEY_POLICY_HOLDER_NAME+" text DEFAULT 'Not Specified',"+KEY_POLICY_HOLDER_ADDRESS+" text DEFAULT 'Not Specified',"
            +KEY_DATE_TIME_LOSS+" text DEFAULT 'Not Specified',"+KEY_DATE_TIME_INTIMATION+" text DEFAULT 'Not Specified',"
            +KEY_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE+" text DEFAULT 'Not Specified',"+ KEY_MANUFACTURE_YEAR +" text DEFAULT 'Not Specified',"
            + KEY_VEHICLE_MAP +" text DEFAULT 'Not Specified');";
```

The values i write to the database aren't null. They have values and i checked them.

**This my data writing method :**

```
public void addAssignment(Assignment assignment) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_JOB_NUMBER, assignment.getJobNumber()); // Job number
    values.put(KEY_TIME_ASSIGNED, assignment.getTimeAssigned());
    values.put(KEY_TIME_RECEIVED, assignment.getTimeReceived());
    //values.put(KEY_STATUS_READ, assignment.getStatusRead());
    //values.put(KEY_STATUS_COMPLETE, assignment.getStatusComplete());
    values.put(KEY_ACCIDENT_ADDRESS, assignment.getAccidentAddress());
    values.put(KEY_ACCIDENT_LAT, assignment.getAccidentLat());
    values.put(KEY_ACCIDENT_LNG, assignment.getAccidentLng());
    values.put(KEY_VEHICLE_NUMBER, assignment.getVehicleNumber());
    values.put(KEY_ENGINE_NUMBER, assignment.getEngineNumber());
    values.put(KEY_CHASSIS_NUMBER, assignment.getChassisNumber());
    values.put(KEY_VEHICLE_MAKE_MODEL, assignment.getVehicleMakeModel());
    values.put(KEY_DRIVER_NAME, assignment.getDriverName());
    values.put(KEY_DRIVER_CONTACT_NUMBER, assignment.getDriverContactNumber());
    values.put(KEY_POLICY_NUMBER, assignment.getPolicyNumber());
    values.put(KEY_POLICY_STATUS, assignment.getPolicyStatus());
    values.put(KEY_POLICY_PERIOD, assignment.getPolicyPeriod());

    values.put(KEY_SUM_INSURED, assignment.getSumInsured());
    values.put(KEY_LAST_ENDORSMENT, assignment.getLastEndorsment());
    values.put(KEY_POLICY_HOLDER_NAME, assignment.getPolicyHolderName());
    values.put(KEY_POLICY_HOLDER_ADDRESS, assignment.getPolicyHolderAddress());
    Log.d("SK---> INSERT ASSIGNMENT", assignment.getDateTimeLoss() + "----" +assignment.getDateTimeIntimation());
    values.put(KEY_DATE_TIME_LOSS, assignment.getDateTimeLoss());
    values.put(KEY_DATE_TIME_INTIMATION, assignment.getDateTimeIntimation());

    values.put(KEY_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE, assignment.getAssignmentType());
    values.put(KEY_MANUFACTURE_YEAR, assignment.getManufactureYear());
    values.put(KEY_VEHICLE_MAP, assignment.getVehicleMap());

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_ASSIGNMENT, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

And following is the code where i retrieve the data. The 26th index to the cursor gives me null. But i checked and 100% sure that at the time of inserting data there is a value being passed to this column and it is not null. But it is not being written to the table. But all the other values are written successfully.

**Data retrieving method :**

```
public Assignment getAssignment(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    /*Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_ASSIGNMENT, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_JOB_NUMBER, KEY_TIME_ASSIGNED, KEY_TIME_RECEIVED, KEY_STATUS_READ,
                    KEY_STATUS_COMPLETE, KEY_ACCIDENT_ADDRESS, KEY_ACCIDENT_LAT, KEY_ACCIDENT_LNG, KEY_VEHICLE_NUMBER, KEY_ENGINE_NUMBER,
                    KEY_CHASSIS_NUMBER, KEY_VEHICLE_MAKE_MODEL, KEY_DRIVER_NAME, KEY_DRIVER_CONTACT_NUMBER, KEY_POLICY_NUMBER,
                    KEY_POLICY_STATUS, KEY_POLICY_PERIOD, KEY_SUM_INSURED, KEY_LAST_ENDORSMENT, KEY_POLICY_HOLDER_NAME, KEY_POLICY_HOLDER_ADDRESS, KEY_DATE_TIME_LOSS, KEY_DATE_TIME_INTIMATION,
                    KEY_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE, KEY_MANUFACTURE_YEAR, KEY_VEHICLE_MAP}, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);*/

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_ASSIGNMENT, null, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Assignment assignment = new Assignment(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),
            cursor.getString(3), cursor.getInt(4), cursor.getInt(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getDouble(7), cursor.getDouble(8),
            cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(10), cursor.getString(11), cursor.getString(12), cursor.getString(13), cursor.getInt(14),
            cursor.getString(15), cursor.getString(16), cursor.getString(17), cursor.getString(18), cursor.getString(19), cursor.getString(20),
            cursor.getString(21),cursor.getString(22),cursor.getString(23), cursor.getString(24), cursor.getString(25), cursor.getString(26));

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    for (int i=0; i<27; i++) {
        Log.e("Values : " + i, cursor.getString(i));
    }

    // Return assignment
    cursor.close();
    return assignment;
}
```

**This is an extract from the logcat which shows the print values from the Data Retrieving method :**

```
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 0: 4
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 1: JB0HEAD1600004889
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 2: 2016-05-09T12:49:33+05:30
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 3: Tue Jun 28 13:47:43 GMT+05:30 2016
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 4: 1
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 5: 0
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 6: RATHNAPURA
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 7: 8.4569
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 8: 85.7563
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 9: 300 6656
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 10: NOT AVAILABLE
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 11: NOT AVAILABLE
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 12: NOT AVAILABLE
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 13: UMASA
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 14: 4225
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 15: PLHEA2016CMC000164
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 16: PAYMENT AUTHORIZED
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 17: 2016-05-02T00:00:00+05:30 2017-05-01T00:00:00+05:30
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 18: 5000
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 19: Not Specified
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 20: A. G. T. D. KUMARA
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 21: NO: 668 / B, UNITY 04, RAJAELA RD, KANTHALE
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 22: 2016-05-09T00:00:00+05:30
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 23: 2016-05-09T00:00:00+05:30
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 24: ST001
06-28 14:13:01.705 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/Values : 25: 2014
06-28 14:13:01.715 14479-14479/com.informaticsint.claimassistant E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.informaticsint.claimassistant, PID: 14479
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
                                                                                   at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
                                                                                   at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:334)
                                                                                   at com.informaticsint.claimassistant.handlers.DatabaseHandler.getAssignment(DatabaseHandler.java:578)
                                                                                   at com.informaticsint.claimassistant.AssignmentDetailsActivity.selectItem(AssignmentDetailsActivity.java:425)
                                                                                   at com.informaticsint.claimassistant.AssignmentDetailsActivity.access$800(AssignmentDetailsActivity.java:72)
                                                                                   at com.informaticsint.claimassistant.AssignmentDetailsActivity$DrawerItemClickListener.onItemClick(AssignmentDetailsActivity.java:302)
                                                                                   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:345)
                                                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1547)
                                                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3821)
                                                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:5841)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Would appreciate any help with this. I have no idea why this is happening. Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Probably `cursor.getString(i)` returning null . try it as as `Log.e("Values : " + i, ""+cursor.getString(i));`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Yes it is returning null. That's the problem. It shouldn't be null. Because i pass valid values to insert and when inserting it does not give me any error, meaning the insert was successful. All the other columns get populated but the last one does not.

Comment: ok then use `values.put(KEY_VEHICLE_MAP,"");` instead of `values.put(KEY_VEHICLE_MAP, assignment.getVehicleMap());` and check  still getting same issue because `assignment.getVehicleMap()` column getting null value

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK sure i'll check that and get back to you

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK It's still passing null. The value does not get written to the table. :/